# how to get VariableElement primitive type

Tags: annotation-processing, annotation-processor

supposing I have annotation on primitive type

```
@Parameter // first data value (0) is default
    public /* NOT private */ int fInput;
```

is there a way to get the type of the element annotated with @Parameter using annotation processing tool?, in this case it is primitive type int. I can get the type if the type is not primitive using the following, but it cannot be applied to primitive type.

```
MoreTypes.asTypeElement(element.asType()).getQualifiedName().toString()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you call `element.asType()`, you get a `TypeMirror`. There are multiple *kinds* of type-mirrors. `TypeElement` may be obtained only for `DeclaredType`, which represent an actual declared class somewhere in code.

If a type is primitive, the actual interface that you get is `PrimitiveType`, which extends `TypeMirror`.

To distinguish between all possible kinds of `TypeMirror` one may check it's `getKind()` property (`instanceof` is discouraged by the API spec). And `TypeKind` enum will tell you the actual type kind; All the primitive types are already included into the enum, e. g. `TypeKind.INT` or `TypeKind.BYTE`.

So that's basically is a way to know whether a type is a primitive, and what kind of primitive.